How to push & pull from two different repos which are created by two different github users without changing windows credentials?
I want to pull from a github repo which is created by user 1 but push different content into github repo of user 2. But for that I have to change the windows credentials related to github every single time before push or pull. How can this be done without changing the credentials just like can be done in linux distributions.

This guide should help you with it https://gist.github.com/rahularity/86da20fe3858e6b311de068201d279e3

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+multiple+accounts
